# How to upload files (documents)/zip in MSSQL using jdbc?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to store documents(doc,ppt,pdf,txt..etc) in MSSQL(server running in AWS). I'm working on the app module (android). I can get the files from the user but I'm not able to upload it to the database.
What I've done so far:

1. Tried to upload the file directly using setBinaryStream
2. Tried to upload the fileInputStream using setBinaryStream
3. No blob type can be declared in this database column

***Update***

Code Requested:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.sm_attachments:

FilePickerDialog filePickerDialog = new FilePickerDialog(SendMailToCustomers.this,properties);
            filePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Files");
            filePickerDialog.show();

            filePickerDialog.setDialogSelectionListener(new DialogSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSelectedFilePaths(String[] files) {
                    for (String file : files) {
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(file));
                        try {
                            File file1 = new File(uri.getPath());
                            //InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(uri.getPath()));
                            byte[] bytesArray = null;

                            bytesArray = new byte[(int) file1.length()];
                            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file1);
                            fileInputStream.read(bytesArray);

                            String sql = "INSERT INTO Storedata (FileName,MyFile) values (?,?)";
                            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            statement.setString(1,"myNewFile");
                            //statement.setBinaryStream(2, /*inputStream*/fileInputStream,fileInputStream.available());
                            statement.setBytes(2, /*inputStream*/bytesArray);
                            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
                            if(row>0){
                                Toast.makeText(SendMailToCustomers.this, "The File was inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onSelectedFilePaths: Inserted File Successfully");
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(SendMailToCustomers.this, "Failed To Insert File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onSelectedFilePaths: Failed To Insert File");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSelectedFilePaths: "+"Exception - "+e.getMessage()+"\n");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
```

The String[] files - are the selected files(Uri) for upload.

Next is the picture of my SQL Database:

[image: Code of my database]

MyFile is varbinary(MAX)

Upon doing this : statement.setBytes(2, /*inputStream*/bytesArray);

I get the below result. But this is around 433984 byte length i.e. bytes read for one file. How should i go about this?

[image: Datbase Pic 2]

Comment: Why not save file after set path on field of table database?

Comment: @quangminhs - Uri.getPath is getting the path of the file in user's phone. I need to send that file to the database.

Comment: Don't post images, post the actual code. And please describe the actual problem. And, most importantly `InputStream.available()` does not do what you think it does, especially not after you've already read data from that stream.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have updated the code..have a look

Comment: Now you are ignoring the fact that `inputStream.read(byte[])` may not read the full file in one go (the return value indicates the number of bytes acutally read. Did you even bother to read the API documentation and a basic tutorial on Java IO? Also you secondary question _"for several files to store in 1 column"_ makes no sense at all: you shouldn't store multiple files in a single column.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you rephrase your question, and describe the actual problem you are trying to solve, instead of asking us to fix the things that are wrong in your current code. As your current code seems to be randomly trying things until they work, that is not a good approach when programming.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah..I didn't see that exception, will read the docs now. My intention is to zip up documents and store them in one column of the database to avoid the headache. What i did was test to see how 1 file would be stored in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164609/discussion-between-supradip-m-and-mark-rotteveel).

Answer (score -1):

The BULK IMPORT would not natively be able to do this however if you are on SQL2005 or greater you can use SSIS. The first step would be to perform an Exectute Process Task and use a zip utility to unzip the file. The second step is to use the SSIS Bulk Insert task to push the data into SQL Server.

Comment: Understood what you're saying but i was trying to upload just one pdf.